# mysql - using Max on two fields

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to run a query to find maximum pDate and maximum id from the dataset below:

id,pDate,CustomerID,refNum
1,2023-07-04,1000,980
2,2023-07-05,1000,982
3,2023-07-05,1001,984
4,2023-07-05,1001,985

output should be:

id,pDate,CustomerID,refNum
2,2023-07-05,1000,982
4,2023-07-05,1001,985

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT pDate, CustomerID,RefNum FROM table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, Max(pDate) as maxpdate FROM table1
GROUP BY CustomerID) sub on t1.CustomerID= sub.CustomerID AND t1.pDate = sub.maxdate
```

The above query is returning the following data:

id,pDate,CustomerID,refNum
2,2023-07-05,1000,982
3,2023-07-05,1001,984
4,2023-07-05,1001,985

Mysql Version is: 5.7.42

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: On what basis do you select the maximum pDate when there are several rows that qualify? It seems that MySQL has, quite reasonably, selected them all. Why should it select row 2? Why does row 4 not fulfil both criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlated subquery with needed ORDER BY and LIMIT 1:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id
  FROM test t2
  WHERE t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
  ORDER BY pDate DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1
  )
```

| id | pDate | CustomerID | refNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-07-05 | 1000 | 982 |
| 4 | 2023-07-05 | 1001 | 985 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wF7dXJQQ)